# I inflate a layout at every click and want to retrieve data from the view in the inflated row

Tags: android

I'm building a GPA calculator. This is my code.  Where am I making a mistake? I know there must be one.  I am a newbie and not grounded at all.  Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_rem"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editCourseName"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/course_name_prompt" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/course_credit_unit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:entries="@array/credit_unit_choices"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:prompt="@string/unit_prompt"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:transitionGroup="false"></Spinner>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/course_grade"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:entries="@array/grade_choices_poly"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:prompt="@string/grade_prompt"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:transitionGroup="false"></Spinner>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!--
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/container">


        </LinearLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

The Java code for my GPA CALCULATOR

```
package com.philipsniche.gpcalculator.activities;

import android.animation.LayoutTransition;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.philipsniche.gpcalculator.R;
import com.philipsniche.gpcalculator.model.Course;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Main layout
    LinearLayout container;


    TextView counter, dispGpa;
    Context context;


    Course course;
    String tempGrade;
    double gradeValue;
    double credit;
    double caltimes = 0;
    double totalcal = 0;
    double totalcredit = 0;
    double finalgpa = 0;
    final double A = 4.0;
    final double AB = 3.5;
    final double B = 3.0;
    final double BC = 2.5;
    final double C = 2.0;
    final double F = 0;
    int courseCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.courseCount);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                addCourseField();
            }
        });


        LayoutTransition transition = new LayoutTransition();
        container.setLayoutTransition(transition);

    }

    @Overrider code here
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_share) {

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onCalculateClick(View view) {

        getDataForCalc();

    }

    public void addCourseField() {

        courseCount += 1;
        counter.setText(" " + courseCount);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        Button btnRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.btnRem);

        btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                courseCount -= 1;
                counter.setText(" " + courseCount);

            }
        });

        container.addView(addView);

    }

    //method to toast error
    public void makeToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void getDataForCalc() {
        int childCount = container.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View v = container.getChildAt(i);

            EditText courseName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editCourseName);
            Spinner gradeSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.course_grade);
            Spinner creditUnitSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.course_credit_unit);

            double cUnit = 0.0;
            tempGrade = "";
            String cName = "";

            cUnit = Double.valueOf(creditUnitSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            tempGrade = gradeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().toUpperCase();
            cName = courseName.getText().toString();

            dispGpa = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGPA);
            //DecimalFormat twodecimal = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            dispGpa.setText("The Selected values are:" + cName + " " + cUnit + " " + tempGrade);

           /* try{
                double cUnit = 0.0;
                tempGrade = "A";
                String cName = "COM 312";

                while (courseCount != 0)
                {
                   cUnit = Double.valueOf(creditUnitSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
                   tempGrade = gradeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().toUpperCase();
                   cName = courseName.getText().toString();
                    switch (tempGrade) {
                        case "A":
                            caltimes = cUnit * A;
                            break;
                        case "AB":
                            caltimes = cUnit * AB;
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            caltimes = cUnit * B;
                            break;
                        case "BC":
                            caltimes = cUnit * BC;
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            caltimes = cUnit * C;
                            break;
                        case "F":
                            caltimes = cUnit * F;
                        default:
                            makeToast("Not a correct grade");
                    }

                    totalcredit = totalcredit + cUnit;
                    totalcal = totalcal * caltimes;

                }

                finalgpa = totalcal/totalcredit;
                dispGpa = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGPA);
                DecimalFormat twodecimal = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                dispGpa.setText("Your GPA: "+ twodecimal.format(finalgpa + "   "+totalcal ));

            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            catch(IllegalStateException e)
            {

            }*/

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing

Comment: Thanks so much @ BadZen @ insomniac my plan is to add a row of 2 spinners and an edittext view to collect course name, its credit unit and grade from the user, the user can click the add button as many as he wants to add a new course. my problem is keeping track of the values entered as the view are inflated. and using them for calculation as each row stands for one course. Pls my question may sound dumb but thats how my brain is seeing it now, i have tried different way but its not working out.